# How to reference data for bootstrap-typeahead?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

This is my data:

```
var markers = {
        "example": {"lat": -83.68088192646843, "lng": -125.270751953125, "type": "town"},
        "anotherexample": {"lat": -58.1548020417031, "lng": -21.318115234375, "type": "town"}
}
```

How do I reference this source of data?

Edit:

The method is this:

`$('.thing').typeahead({source: markers});`

But that doesn't work and I think it's because `markers` isn't the correct syntax to select my markers object. What should I use instead?

Comment: What do you mean by _reference_ ? You need to be more explicit. What are you trying to get as a result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this:

```
names = []; 
for (var k in markers) {
    if (markers.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        names.push(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to serialize the object in some ways.
In my [example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/PDShf/) I concatenated each entry to obtain a certain string :

```
var markers_as_str = Array();
for(var index in markers) {
    var marker = markers[index];
    var str = index+" : "+marker.lat+" "+marker.lng+" "+marker.type;
    markers_as_str.push(str);
}

$('#strs').typeahead({
    source: markers_as_str
});
```

You could customize the `matcher` and `sorter` options to check specific properties. But you would have difficulties with the display of the choices, so you'd have to override the `updater` option. And all this would go a bit too far, as you may not need it.

Comment: I've just figured out a cleaner way to convert it to an array. Though the typeahead still won't work. I'm going to make a fiddle to test.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on the matter, [How to use rich objects and typed objects with Bootstrap Typeahead](http://victorblog.com/2013/06/21/how-to-use-rich-objects-and-typed-objects-with-bootstrap-typeahead/). The key is typing your objects to some class which has a `toString()` method to serialize and a `fromString()` method to deserialize (to be used in the Bootstrap Typeahead `updater` function to reference an object of the original type). In my blog, I use `UsState` as an example:

```
UsState.prototype.toString = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
};

UsState.fromString = function(serializedState) {
    return $.extend(new UsState(), JSON.parse(serializedState));
};
```

Then in the Typeahead definition for `updater`:

```
updater: function(state) {
    state = UsState.fromString(state);
    $stateMessage.html('<strong>' + state.name + '</strong> has ' + state.numElectoralVotes + ' electoral votes.');
    return state.name;
},
```

Note the definition of other Typeahead methods to handle your objects properly:

```
highlighter: function(state) {
    return $.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.highlighter.call(this, state.name);
},
```